# List Google Calendar Events Matching Multiple Extended Properties?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar API v3 in a WPF/C# desktop application, part of which retrieves a list of events from a given Google Calendar for a specified date range. The events have a property called `EventType`, which is stored as a shared extended property on the Calendar event object, and is held as an `Enum` in my application.

Shared extended properties are a `Dictionary<string, string>` object within a Google Calendar event, so mine are set as:

`['EventType', 'Training']`

`['EventType', 'Meeting']`

`['EventType', 'Demonstration']`

`['EventType', 'Social']`

...etc.

These extended properties have all been set fine and I can retrieve them without an issue, however I'd like to be able to filter by multiple event types (for example, show all events which are either Meeting or Demonstration).

This is my current code:

```
try
        {
            List<GoogleCalendarEvent> eventList = new List<GoogleCalendarEvent>();

            using (CalendarService service = GoogleCalendarService.GetService())
            {
                EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List(CalendarId);
                request.TimeMin = DateFrom;
                request.TimeMax = DateTo;
                request.ShowDeleted = false;
                request.SingleEvents = true;
                request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

                List<string> eventTypes = new List<string>();

                foreach (var type in EventTypes)
                    eventTypes.Add($"EventType={type.ToString()}");

                request.SharedExtendedProperty = eventTypes;

                Events events = await request.ExecuteAsync();

                if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                        eventList.Add(new GoogleCalendarEvent(eventItem, this));
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception($"No events found for the time range {DateFrom.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")} - {DateTo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")} within calendar '{Summary}'");

                return (true, eventList, "");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (false, null, ex.Message);
        }
```

The request.SharedExtendedProperty object is a `Google.Apis.Util.Repeatable<string>` object, which inherits from `IEnumerable<string>`.

The above code doesn't retrieve any results because (I believe) it's looking for events that match ALL of the given `EventType` values rather than ANY of the values. When I run this code with only one `EventType`, the events are retrieved correctly. There is very little documentation on this on Google's API pages and I've tried Googling but no luck, only people who are looking to match multiple properties rather than finding one property with multiple potential values.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Mind trying to test this using the APIs explorer.  https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.list.   We need to verify that this will even work with the api.   Assuming that works try sending it exactly it looks like on googles side its just a string not a dictionary eventTypes.Add("['EventType', 'Training']");

Comment: No it doesn't work, it seems to just take the latest value added and searches for that only, ignoring the others. Unless it's just the way that the request is constructed, it added each sharedExtendedProperty to the URL string and only used the last value added.

Comment: Sounds like a "Feature" in the API then.